# NoMethodError (undefined method `created_at' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, nomethoderror

I have the following Rails code in my `conversations_controller`:

A user may be : `master` or `rookie`.

```
@conversations = current_user.master.conversations.all
@conversations = @conversations.sort_by { |c| c.messages.last.created_at }.reverse
```

But on running this I'm getting a `no method error` for `created_at`. 
If I do a `puts` like this:

```
puts "Sorted: #{@conversations.map { |c| c.messages.last}}"
```

this gives me the following response:

```
Sorted: [#<Message id: 9, content: "some content", user_id: 3, conversation_id: 1, created_at: "2017-03-01 00:00:36", updated_at: "2017-03-01 00:00:36", attachment_url: []>, nil, #<Message id: 11, content: "new message", user_id: 3, conversation_id: 6, created_at: "2017-03-01 15:15:58", updated_at: "2017-03-01 15:15:58", attachment_url: []>]
```

If I'm getting `created_at` then why can't I extract the last messages `created_At` to compare and sort?

On doing a simple

```
puts "The conversations sorted are: #{@conversations.map { |c| c.messages}}"
```

Gives me the following response:

```
The conversations sorted are: [#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Message id: 1, content: "Hey there! This is my first message.", user_id: 1, conversation_id: 1, created_at: "2017-02-28 23:57:46", updated_at: "2017-02-28 23:57:46", attachment_url: []>, #<Message id: 2, content: "Thank you for your message. I am a coach.", user_id: 3, conversation_id: 1, created_at: "2017-02-28 23:57:46", updated_at: "2017-02-28 23:57:46", attachment_url: []>, #<Message id: 9, content: "adsdadasd", user_id: 3, conversation_id: 1, created_at: "2017-03-01 00:00:36", updated_at: "2017-03-01 00:00:36", attachment_url: ["https://ace-up-www.s3.amazonaws.com/message-attachments%2Fbd450b1e-f85c-47ec-94c7-c539809f8d68%2Frecommendation-bg.jpg"]>]>, #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>, #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Message id: 10, content: "Add a new message", user_id: 8, conversation_id: 6, created_at: "2017-03-01 14:58:29", updated_at: "2017-03-01 14:58:29", attachment_url: []>, #<Message id: 11, content: "new message", user_id: 3, conversation_id: 6, created_at: "2017-03-01 15:15:58", updated_at: "2017-03-01 15:15:58", attachment_url: []>]>]
```

As you can see there is an empty `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>` which is probably getting translated to `nil`.
Any help in debugging this?

Comment: there are `nil` values in the array, right here `... updated_at: "2017-03-01 00:00:36", attachment_url: []>, nil, #<Message id: 11...`, see that `nil` ?

Comment: @fanta you're correct and I noticed the same thing just after posting the question, so I edited my question to add more details.

Comment: why don't you try something like `@conversations = current_user.master.conversations.joins(:messages).order("messages.created_at DESC")` ?, that way your code will be faster.

Comment: That would return multiple Conversation objects. One for each message in the conversation. You could add `.distinct` to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occured when you tried to get the created at attribute of the converstions last message which actually dont have any messages with it.

```
@conversations = current_user.master.conversations.joins(:messages)
@conversations = @conversations.sort_by { |c| c.messages.last.created_at }.reverse
```

By joining the messages with the conversations only the conversation with atleast one message will be retrieved so by that i think the issue get fixed.